# @fullcalendar/angular - Events not working

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

i've added @fullcalendar/angular in my angular application but my [events] doesn't work.

in my app.module.ts:

```
FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([
  dayGridPlugin,
  interactionPlugin,
  timeGridPlugin
])

imports: [
    ...
    ...
    FullCalendarModule
  
  ]
```

//.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import { CalendarOptions, FullCalendarComponent } from '@fullcalendar/angular';
import { EventInput } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import { title } from 'process';
import { event } from '../common/models/event';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-profile',
  templateUrl: './my-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-profile.component.css']
})
export class MyProfileComponent implements OnInit {
posts =[]; 
  //full calendar specified , static : true is obligatory
  @ViewChild("fullcalendar", { static: true })
  calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent;
 ngOnInit(): void {
    
  
  
  this.service.getEvents(this.username).subscribe(
    (data) => {
     
      for(let i = 0; i <= Object.keys(data).length; i++){
          const e = new event;
          if(data[i]!=undefined){
          
          e.setTitle(data[i].title);
          e.setStart(data[i].start);
          e.setEnd(data[i].end);
          e.setColor(data[i].color);
          this.posts.push(e);
          }
      }
      
      console.log(" my events " + JSON.stringify(this.posts));
      
      
    }
  )
    
        
        
      }
   

}
```

in my .html file

```
<full-calendar #fullcalendar [events]="posts"  defaultView="dayGridDay"  [options]="calendarOptions" ></full-calendar>
```

i have this error Can't bind to 'events' since it isn't a known property of 'full-calendar'.

i also tried an other solution to set myEvents fetched from database to calendarOptions but it doesn't work.

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
  initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
  dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this), // bind is important!
  locale: 'fr',
  events: this.posts
}
```

Comment: are you sure "events" is aproperty of full-calendar, because I didn't any property event in the official documentation https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular

Comment: @Elmehdi thank you for your comment. i tried to set my events fetched from database in the CalendarOptions like this calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
  initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
  dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this), // bind is important!
  locale: 'fr',
  events: this.posts
}

Answer (score 2):

You will just need to use full-calendar exactly like what's in the documentation.
First you create your calendarOptions inside your component's Typescript file:

```
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this), // bind is important!
    events: posts // here you should put your events data and it should be an array
  };
```

Then you append calendarOptions to full-calendar's "options" property:

```
<full-calendar [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>
```

Comment: @YounesBOUAZIZI not working _how_, specifically? Do you have an error message in the console, perhaps? Have you debugged to see if the `posts` data is definitely populated when its passed to the calendar? Also, can we see what it's populated with, please? If you specify your event objects incorrectly, fullCalendar will simply ignore them, but you won't see an error.

Comment: @ADyson thank you for your comment, my 'posts' is populated like this [{"title":"title 1","start":"2020-10-01 16:00:00","end":"2020-10-01 18:00:00","color":"green"},{"title":"title 2","start":"2020-09-30 19:00:00","end":"2020-09-30 20:00:00","color":"green"},{"title":"title 3","start":"2020-09-30 20:00:00","end":"2020-09-30 21:00:00","color":"green"},{"title":"title 4","start":"2020-09-30 22:42:00","end":"2020-10-01 00:37:00","color":"green"}] but fullcalendar ignore my event object.

Comment: @YounesBOUAZIZI ok thanks. So, just to check, is `posts` a string, or an array?

Comment: @ADyson posts it's an array, i initialized like this posts =[]; and i populated like this:for(let i = 0; i <= Object.keys(data).length; i++){
          const e = new event;
          if(data[i]!=undefined){
          //console.log("titre " + data[i].start);
          e.setTitle(data[i].title);
          e.setStart(data[i].start);
          e.setEnd(data[i].end);
          e.setColor(data[i].color);
          this.posts.push(e); 
          }
      }

Comment: @ADyson my event is like this:my object event is like this:                                                                                             export class event {
    public title: String;
    public start: Date;
    public end: Date;
    public color: String;  // with getters and setters

Comment: Then it should work. The only other thing I can think is that somehow it isn't populated yet at the moment you pass the variable to the calendar. It's hard to know, please a) use the debugger to check it, and b) update your question to show all this code in context, then we can try to track the execution path. I wonder if something is happening asynchronously, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed is that the value of 'this' in the event-handlers (the js click events like dateClick & dateSelect) is the FullCalendar, and not the angular component!

This means that to dynamically add an event you can do this:

```
public selectDate(event: DateClickArg) {
  console.log(event);
  this.addEvent({
    start: event.date,
    title: "Dentist",
  });
}
```

I had the same issue, now that I'm looking more into this, I notice this in the angular plugin's documentation:

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
  initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
  dateClick: this.handleDateClick.bind(this), // bind is important!
```

This binding is indeed important! Adding the binding allows me the access the calendarOptions in the eventHandler again:

```
public selectDate(event: DateClickArg) {
    console.log(event);

    this.calendarOptions.events = this.calendarEvents.concat({
      start: event.date,
      title: "Dentist",
    });
  }
```